# Xcode 3 Error Starting Executable

Tags: xcode

I have created simple Objective c & Cocoa application and when i build & run it am getting an error saying :

```
Error Starting Executable
Check its arguments and the debugger console.
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 1777:(os/kern) failure(0x5).
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Xcode go crazy, just creating a new app or a new class! Try to clean all targets, close xcode, reboot, reopen xcode and relaunch all. Id it doesn't work try to redo a new app and copy all classes and storyboard/xib. This should solve the problem!